# System stored procedure to create a new sequence? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sequence

I'm looking for a way to create a new sequence given a name, min, max and current value.

Using the `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement is a less preferable option, since I would have to use string concatenation in order to create the final SQL statement for execution.

All I need to do with the created sequence is to fetch the next value using the `sp_sequence_get_range` system stored procedure, which accepts sequence name as a parameter. No further modifications to the sequence is required.

Is there any other option to create a sequence, for instance, by using some obscure system stored procedure?

**Note 1**:
***What I'm trying to accomplish:***
I need to manage ranges of numbers in a web application.
The user should be able to create a new range, and to get the next value in an existing range. In case of exhaustion - user should receive an error.
My choices are: manage a table of ranges, or manage sequences. I would think that sequences are more suitable for this matter.

**Note 2**: additional reading: [CREATE SEQUENCE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx), [sp_sequence_get_range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878352.aspx)

Comment: Do you want to add some background? There might be a better way to do this. Are you expecting to need to manage a large number of unique sequences? Once you've create the sequence, how are you going to use it? if you created it with dynamic SQL you'll need to use it with dynamic SQL (because you don't know the name)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid

I'm going to fetch the next value using `sp_sequence_get_range`, which accepts sequence name as a parameter.

No further modifications to the sequence is required.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about `sp_sequence_get_range`. So what is it that decides the sequence name? Is it an application or a deployment or something?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
The application will call a stored procedure to create a sequence with a given name and other values.

Comment: I still don't understand why you would need to dynamically create a sequence. Anyway someone else may know the answer to your actual question. Good luck

Comment: Using string concatenation is not exactly the end of the world.

Comment: @DanBracuk
Currently, I don't have any other options

Comment: With so little information on what you're going to do with these sequences, I'm not sure you need a sequence at all. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @SqlZim
I need to manage ranges of numbers in a web application .
The user should be able to create a new range, and to get the next value in existing range. In case of exhaustion - user should receive an error.

My possible choices are: manage a table of ranges, or manage sequences. I would think that sequences are more suitable for this matter.